# transform JSON object into DataFrame on SPARK

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, dataframe, ibm-cloud

I'm getting a stream of tweets in JSON format using a Python notebook on Apache Spark on IBM Bluemix. I want to turn the JSON object into a dataframe. The closest thing i have found is:

`json_obj = {"tweet": "hey man", "name": "Alan"} #mock example`

`tweetsDF = sqlContext.read.json("file path")`

Now, I don't wanna load a file. I just wanna take that JSON variable and convert it into dataframe format. That way i can apply it to the tweets variable. Any idea how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

First convert the JSON object into an RDD[String], then apply `sqlContext.read.json'. Here is example code in Scala

```
val json_obj = sc.parallelize(Array("""{"tweet": "hey man", "name": "Alan"}""", """{"tweet": "what's up", "name": "Bertha"}"""))
val tweetsDF = sqlContext.read.json(json_obj)
tweetsDF.show()
//+------+---------+
//|  name|    tweet|
//+------+---------+
//|  Alan|  hey man|
//|Bertha|what's up|
//+------+---------+
```